Delay in GCP Billing Updates and Managing Cost Thresholds for Cloud Services
I've been using a Google Cloud Platform service to run multiple cloudRun jobs, but the billing dashboard has not updated the costs associated with these operations for over 50 minutes. The current billing status remains as:
Cost: $120.97
Discounts: $0.00
Promotions and others: $0.00
Subtotal: $120.97


Is it common for GCP billing updates to take hours? How long should I typically wait to see updated charges after running services?
How can I ensure I don't exceed my budget if there's a significant delay in billing updates? Specifically, if I were to accidentally run millions of jobs and wish to stop service usage once I reach a $2,000 threshold, what mechanisms does GCP offer to prevent overspending and potentially close the project or stop the services automatically?


SO is not a support forum
